# Hover effect on <hr> in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

I've got a table with a <hr>, a title and a body text. I put the hover effect on the whole table but for the <hr>, it doesn't change the colour when mouseover the table only when mouseover the line. I need it to change colour as soon as the mouse touches the table like the rest. I tried various things but none seem to have worked.

How can I get the <hr> line to change the colour to white like the rest of the table when mouseover anywhere on the table? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7eS7w/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><hr /></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">This is the Header</a></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="#">some row content</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
hr{
border:1px solid;
float:left;
align:left;
width:30%;
background-color:#991f33;
color:#991f33;
}
hr:hover{
background-color:#fff;
color:#fff;
}

table {
    border:0;
    background-color:#dcdcdc;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    padding:20px;
}

thead tr a{
    color: #911f33;
}

tbody tr{
    font-size:10px;
    line-height:19px;
    color: #911f33;
}

table:hover, table:hover a{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#911f33;
}

tr a{
    color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td><hr id="hrr"/></td>
```

css is

```
table:hover #hrr
{
      border:1px solid blue;
}
```